# How to deploy dbExpress database application without SQL native client 2008 installation?

Tags: sql, delphi, delphi-xe2, dbexpress

I am deploying dbExpress database application on a machine which doesn't have SQL Native client installed. I have copied `DBXMSS.dll` but I am getting an error like

> DBX Error: Driver could not be properly initialized. Client library may be missing, not installed properly, or wrong version

Is it possible to run this application without installing the SQL Native client 2008? If yes, please advise.

Thanks.

Comment: AFAIK, you have to install the Native Client, because it requires the DLLs from that client to make the connection.

Comment: AFAIKTOO you need them. You can just download the client from Microsoft if you need it (google "download native sql 2008 client"), they are in the 'Feature Pack'.

Comment: Is it possible to manually copy / register DLLs from SQL Native client separately which will help to get rid of this error?

Comment: Does your questions come from the need to deploy your app? Then try to have your installer call the MS SQL Client Setup first. I did that with MSDE (years ago) and it works fine. You need to check the MS license if their installer is redistributable, and you need to properly handle installation errors (ExitCode).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not possible.  You must have the native client installed.  DBX requires that the drivers be present.